# Can't rename Visual Studio 2010 Project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have a Visual Studio 2010 Solution, that is also under source control (TFS 2010). Usually, I have no problem renaming a sub-project; just right-click, rename, and life is good!

However, I now have one project that I'm trying to rename, but whenever i right-click, type in a new name, and then hit enter, it goes right back to the old name!

I must be losing my mind here!

Comment: why don't you just rename it in source control?

Comment: Did you get any message at Visual Studio -> View -> Output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end it seemed like a TFS issue. THere was a lingering shelveset that was mapped to the project that wouldn't allow me to modify it at all. Once I was able to get my TFS admin to make the necessary changes, all was well!

Answer (score 1):

You probably already have a file with the name you are trying to use on the filesystem though not as part of the solution/project.

Use the windows explorer to find and delete this file and you should be good to go.

Comment: I don't think that's it. I'm renaming from "MyProject.Tests.IntegrationTests.ClientProxy" to "MyProject.ProxyTest" because TFS was having issues with paths exceeding 255 chars. I can assure you I have no file/folder with the name "MyProject.ProxyTest"

Comment: @ErOx - did you check? This has happened to me when I started a rename and stopped it.

Comment: @ErOx - Too bad. I will leave my answer here, as it might help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to do [Reset Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

> The command "devenv /resetsettings" will restore Visual Studio back to its original factory state. If you have previously saved your settings from option 1 above, you can pass them as a parameter: "devenv /resetsettings ".

Or else if you have saved any previous settings try to import by this path  `"Tools" > "Import and Export Settings…"` and your problem get resolved.

If this is v1 sorry you can't rename it as it is mentioned here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/tfsgeneral/thread/9e50138e-46f2-4f7f-ba09-e5624d30250b/

Answer (score 0):

I tried to go offline from TFS but it gave no results =(

So, then I tried to delete 'SolutionName.suo' file and it made the trick! I was able to rename my project. Buggy VS 2010 =(